# Which files should I ignore in subversion for a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn

I can see I should ignore tmp/ and log/ but are there any other files which shouldn't be in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a public repository (or one where unauthorised people can look in to) you could ignore `config/database.yml` as well, since it contains information (usernames and passwords) about your database you might want to keep private.

Nonetheless, you'd need to readme/explanation, since it breaks your application when checking out.

Comment: This also applies to other config-data like s3.yml files you might have. I check whether the required files exist on startup and print a warning/exit.
Some people exclude `schema.rb` but this will lead to issues once you have a Continuous Integration server setup.

Comment: Yes, leaving `schema.rb` out is a bad thing to do! And adding the warning/exit upon starting the application might indeed be a good solution besides the readme/explanation.